# Out-Of-The-Box (md_string)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, dropbox

Does anyone know anything about an extension called md_string?

I am using a WordPress plugin called [Out-Of-The-Box](https://codecanyon.net/item/outofthebox-dropbox-plugin-for-wordpress-/5529125) but to make it work I have to enable that extension on the server. This is the message I get:

`md_string extension enabled?   The required md_string extension is not enabled on your server. Please enable this extension.`

I've even googled it everything and on the plugin's forum and have not found anything about the extension.

Any help will be kindly appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe `mb_string`?

Comment: I've heard  of mbstring, but not md_string. Depending on your hosting situation, you can may need tech support to enable it or you will need root level access.

Comment: The source code for Out-of-the-Box does contain a check for the extension mbstring and dies with an error if it is not installed and enabled. What is your operating system? Many make it very easy to install and enable mbstring. For example, I use RedHat and all I have to do is type `sudo yum install php-mbstring` on the command line.

Comment: @BA_Webimax I've never heard of md_string either but I know of mb_string or mbstring and i don't know if that's what they mean!!

Comment: @kainaw I have Centos 5.6 (final). I tried installing mbstring using yum but i get this errors:  1)--> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-45.el5_11 is needed by package php-mbstring-5.1.6-45.el5_11.x86_64 (updates)
2)Error: Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-45.el5_11 is needed by package php-mbstring-5.1.6-45.el5_11.x86_64 (updates)

Comment: From the sounds of it, you are in need of some updated server software. Current CentOS is 5.11. There are tutorials on how to get up to PHP 5.6 for that version. You are likely to continue to have issues with WordPress since it requires PHP5.6 or higher and many plugins will have similar requirements.

Comment: There is more than one php package set for Centos. Do "yum list | grep mbstring" to see if there are more packages, such as php53-mbstring or php56-mbstring. Assuming you have php installed, you may have installed php53-common or php56-common instead of php-common.

Comment: @kainaw Doing "yum list | grep mbstring" i get this:                                              php-mbstring.x86_64                        5.1.6-45.el5_11             updates  and
php53-mbstring.x86_64                      5.3.3-26.el5_11             updates

Comment: @CarlosAleman Since you can't install php-mbstring, I bet you have php53 installed. So, install php53-mbstring.